# save state of togglebutton android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work please? I am trying to save the state of the togglebutton, but everytime I close the app and start again, it goes back to off. I want the state to be remembered, so when someone adds something to their favourites, to remember it as being added to favourite.

private String state = "State";

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu, menu);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton);
    toggleButton.setChecked(readState());
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                // The toggle is enabled
                toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
            else 
                // The toggle is disabled
                toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));

            saveState(isChecked);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void saveState(boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(state, isFavourite).apply();
}
private boolean readState() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(state, true);
}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton);
    toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
    toggleButton.setChecked(readState());
}
```

Comment: You could use local storage. Or a database (probably an overkill).

Comment: You are setting a the checked state twice...delete the following line

*toggleButton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", true));*...

Comment: Also would suggest to use a class private string like **private String state = "State"** and use this in the **saveState** and **readState** methods. **editor.putBoolean(state, isFavourite);** and **sharedPreferences.getBoolean(state, true);**

Comment: thank you, just replaced it with a String, and removed that line, but still not saving the state. It goes back to original every time a new activity is opened,

Answer (score 1):

you're reading from one `SharedPreferences` file, but writing into a different one.

change the init line of `sharedPreferences` in `saveState` to:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Also, instead of using `setOnClickListener`, you should instead use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html), and the example code:

```
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Full code with fixes:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu, menu);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton);
    toggleButton.setChecked(readState());
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
                toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
            }
            saveState(isChecked);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void saveState(boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("State", isFavourite).apply();
}
private boolean readState() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
}
```

Comment: After changing it to this in saveState, the favourite button doesn't change when clicked on

Comment: added that and still doesn't work - in the if statement added:toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
                    isFavourite = false;
                    saveState(isFavourite);

Comment: and  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isFavourite) {
               // boolean isFavourite = readState();
                if (isFavourite)                       is that correct?

Comment: no, first change both `readState` and `saveState` to use the same `sharedPreferences` file if you haven't already. Next, the `onCheckedChanged` method gives you the current state of the **UI button** not the state in your shared-prefs, you should **write** the state into your shared-prefs in this method, not read.

Comment: i've added the entire code from your question along with fixes, good luck

Comment: also, you might want to put `toggleButton.setChecked(readState());` in your Activity's `onCreate` method as well

Comment: After updating my answer, doesn't work and adding to onCreate, still doesn't work

Comment: PreferenceManager is deprecated.

Comment: `android.preference.PreferenceManager` is deprecated, but `androidx.preference.PreferenceManager` is not, just make sure you import from the correct library you want to use

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the state of your togglebutton twice.
So, these lines are not necessary. Delete the below lines.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
toggleButton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", true));
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I removed those lines, but still doesn't save the state. Goes back to off when starting a new activity

Comment: try the updated answer. Improved logic and clean code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43166740/6176006

Comment: Or try to add `toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton);
    toggleButton.setChecked(readState());` these line in `onCreate` of your activity.

Comment: I tried that and didn't work, and also added this to my onCreate but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleButton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", true));
```

The above line is resetting the state of checkbox. Hence it needs to be removed. Moreover the Strings like "**Favourite**" and "**State**" should be defined as constants.In case of spelling mistakes in one or the other line,this can also lead to unexpected results.

Comment: I removed those lines, but still doesn't save the state. Goes back to off when starting a new activity